# SQLASPMembershipProvider not connecting to Database

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

I have created a web app using the SQLASPMembership provider and and everything works fine off my development machine. However when I publish it out to the web server it fails to connect to the database (at least that is what I think is happening, it is diffcult to tell as there is no error message).

I have taken the same connection string listed below that the Membership provider uses and created a row count query against the aspnet_Membership that returns the correct no problem. Additionally I created an ODBC connection to the database as well, so I know that I can see the database.

```
<add name="connectionSQL"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  connectionString="Password=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*******;Initial Catalog=IdentityManagement;Data Source=sql2005dev"
   />

<providers>
   <add connectionStringName="connectionSQL" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
        enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
        requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" 
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="4" 
        minRequiredPasswordLength="6" passwordAttemptWindow="5" 
        name="SQLASPMembershipProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
</providers>
```

I have checked out every other solution I have found. I use TCP, there is no firewall issue, read write permissions are granted.

How can this be fixed?